# How to define a custom function in deluge?

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I want to create an automated email in Zoho Cliq that sends a message to everyone every morning. In the message there is a button that should call the sendMsg function.

How can I define the sendMsg function?

The idea is that by pressing the button another message should be sent back to me.

Thanks for the help

```
response = map();
response.put("text","Wie startest du heute in deinen Tag?");
card = map();
card.put("title","Guten Morgen ☕");
response.put("card",card);
buttonsList = list();
buttonsList0 = map();
buttonsList0.put("label","Remote");
buttonsList0.put("type","+");
action = map();
action.put("type","invoke.function");
data = map();
data.put("name","sendMsg");
action.put("data",data);
buttonsList0.put("action",action);
buttonsList.add(buttonsList0);
response.put("buttons",buttonsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to define a custom function, you need to start with the "function" keyword, followed by the name of the function and its parameters enclosed in parentheses.

For example:

```
function my_function(input1, input2) {

}
```